# Nav в структуре html

Tags: html, main

Как понять, когда nav нужно писать в header или в main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nav в header -> основное меню сайта

nav в main -> навигация основного контента (если она у тебя есть)

прочитай про Семантические элементы HTML5[image: введите сюда описание изображения]